# What does a string between percent signs, like `SET(%MY_VAR% ON)` mean in cmake?

Tags: cmake

Stumbled upon something like this in a cmake file and couldn't find the syntax explanation neither in cmake documentation, nor on the Internet.

```
SET(%MY_LIB_TYPE% ON)
```

The same line is defined in a `.cmake` and in a similarly named `.cmake.in` files, and `MY_LIB_NAME` does not appear anywhere else.

What does `%string%` syntax do?

Comment: I think it is a usual string from CMake perspective. It is probably a placeholder for some other tool.

Answer (score 0):

In CMake, *nothing*. **It looks like a template placeholder for something that's generating CMake files.** I believe this is the most likely option.

Otherwise, `%` is *technically* an allowable variable name character in CMake, though you have to indirect through another variable to read it.

```
$ cat test.cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

set(%FOO% bar)
set(var "%FOO%")
message("${${var}}")

$ cmake -P test.cmake
bar
```